# (linked list) warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am getting following warning

**warning message:**

warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

**warning at following line:**

for (ptr = &hashTable[hashFunction(s)]; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next)

**My problem:**

I just have no idea to correct this. What is the problem and how to fix this?
Thank you very much.

**Below is source code:**

```
typedef struct {
 struct SinglyLinkedList *next;
 char name[50];                     // key
 int mid;                           // mark
 int final;
} SinglyLinkedList;

// Global Variables
int tableSize;
SinglyLinkedList *hashTable;

...

SinglyLinkedList* find (char *s)
{
    SinglyLinkedList *ptr;

    for (ptr = &hashTable[hashFunction(s)]; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        if (strcmp(s, ptr->name) == 0) {
            return ptr;    //found
        }
    } 
 return NULL;    //not found
}

...

int main(void) {
...

hashTable = (SinglyLinkedList*) malloc (sizeof(SinglyLinkedList) * tableSize);

...
}
```

**ADDED CODE:**

```
int hashFunction(char *s) {
    int hashValue;
    
    for(hashValue = 0; *s != '\0'; s++) {
        hashValue += *s;
    }
    
    return hashValue % tableSize;
}
```

Comment: could it be that `struct SinglyLinkedList` within the `typedef struct {[...]} SinglyLinkedList` is in fact a different/new/local type? As `SinglyLinkedList` is not defined yet, it seems weird you could generate a pointer object.

Comment: @wildplasser sorry, just added code for hashTable

Comment: Add an extra level of inderection. And make `hashTable` an array of pointers (or a pointer to pointer, and malloc() the size you want) . BTW: tableSize is uninitialized.

Comment: `typedef struct {
 struct SinglyLinkedList *next;` --> `typedef struct SinglyLinkedList {
 struct SinglyLinkedList *next;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually typedef node's like this.  It got rid of the warning for me.

```
typedef struct SinglyLinkedList_TAG {
   struct SinglyLinkedList_TAG *next;
   char name[50];                     // key
   int mid;                           // mark
   int final;
} SinglyLinkedList;
```